# How to install docker on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, docker

After installing EPEL repository and enabling EPEL, I tried the following:

```
# yum install docker-io || yum --enablerepo=epel install docker-io
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.btte.net
 * epel: mirrors.yun-idc.com
 * extras: mirrors.btte.net
 * updates: mirrors.btte.net
No package docker-io available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

In CentOS 7, how can I install docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/Docker), docker is inside the CentOS-Extras repository of CentOS 7 and can be installed without the need for enabling EPEL.

Please note: As of CentOS 7, the correct name of the package should be simply `docker`, while in the EPEL repository for CentOS 6, it is yet called `docker-io`.) I guess that's the problem why it fails for you. Hope this helps!

**Some additional comments (thanks to @Martin Preusse for the hints):**
The packages in the `extras` repository are a little bit outdated right now. Available version is 0.11.1, while the current stable version of docker is 1.2.0.

While docker was available in the [EPEL repository for CentOS 6](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_d.group.html) as `docker-io` (because `docker` is conflicting with the package name of a system tray dock), it is not available in the [beta EPEL repository  for CentOS 7](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_d.group.html). And even worse: The version in the EPEL for CentOS 6 is 1.1.2 and much newer than the current version in the official extras repository of CentOS 7.

Comment: Do you know which version is available in the CentOS-Extra repository? I hope they keep up with Docker development and update the Extra repo.

Comment: @Martin Preusse Ouch, good point! Seems like they don't do right now. Version still seems to be 0.11.1

Comment: Keeping track of repo versions can be annoying ... docker-io in CentOS 6 EPEL is 1.1.2. What is the general policy of updating the Extra repo?

Comment: @Martin Preusse I don't know the policy. It seems that all packages in the [`extras`](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/) repository are last updated on 06-Jul-2014.

Comment: This is now the recommended way to install from the Docker : https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't optimal, but I pulled a recent rpm from FC19 and used that on CentOS7.  I used docker-io-1.1.2-3.fc19.x86_64 from:

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27150558/dir/fedora_19/com/docker-io-1.1.2-3.fc19.x86_64.rpm.html

and then performed a local rpm install.  I have not had any issues. My CentOS version is CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

This wasn't my preferred way of doing this, but it was better than being so far back in terms of versions.

Answer (score -2):

You can install docker using repo or a package file as below:

```
yum install -y yum-utils

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Verify that the fingerprint matches `060A 61C5 1B55 8A7F 742B 77AA C52F EB6B 621E 9F35` and accept the GPG key if requested to do so.

For the installation of a particular version you can refer the command below :

```
yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
```

OR

You can also install it without adding the repository on the server.
Installation steps using the package download Visit this link: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos Then select your preferred CentOS version. Once you've found the.rpm file for the Docker version you wish to instal, navigate to x86 64/stable/Packages/.